# Why does django queryset.extra() throws OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm using **Django ORM** with **MySQL** and wasting a lot of time with querys. For some "advanced" cases i decided to go for raw queries, since for those, i couldn't make it with annotations. The problem with raw queries is that the don't add a "field" to the queryset like annotations or aggregations. So, **i'm using** *extra*. But now i'm facing a **problem**:

```
qs_products = Productos.objects.all()
qs_productos.extra({
    "stock":
    """
        SELECT SUM(items.cantidad)
        FROM 
            `encargosProveedor_listado_articulos` AS encargos, 
            `itemArticulosProveedor`AS items, `articulos` as articulos
        WHERE 
            encargos.itemarticulosproveedor_id=items.id and 
            articulos.id=items.articulos_id
        GROUP BY articulos.producto_id
    """
    })
```

This is **the result for this query** directly from my db admin:

```
+---------------------+
| SUM(items.cantidad) |
+---------------------+
|          14         |
+---------------------+
|          4          |
+---------------------+
```

But when running this code under django using **extra()**

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

**What is the problem for returning more than one row?** The query is returning two rows because i have two products, its reasonable. I want to assign *stock* to each one of the products.

**Alternatives? Suggestions? Hints?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do a join between the outer query and the `extra` subquery, and the database needs an explicit join clause to do that. I believe you can add a WHERE clause to the `extra` for it to work:

```
qs_productos.extra({
    "stock":
    """
        SELECT SUM(items.cantidad)
        FROM 
            `encargosProveedor_listado_articulos` AS encargos, 
            `itemArticulosProveedor`AS items, `articulos` as articulos
        WHERE 
            articulos.producto_id = productos.id and
            encargos.itemarticulosproveedor_id=items.id and 
            articulos.id=items.articulos_id       
        GROUP BY articulos.producto_id
    """
})
```

`productos` in `articulos.producto_id = productos.id` would need to be replaced by the actual table name from the main query.

Since `extra` is lined up for deprecation (not quite deprecated yet though as of Django 2.2), here's the equivalent [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) query:

```
qs_productos.annotate(stock=RawSQL(
    """
        SELECT SUM(items.cantidad)
        FROM 
            `encargosProveedor_listado_articulos` AS encargos, 
            `itemArticulosProveedor`AS items, `articulos` as articulos
        WHERE 
            articulos.producto_id = productos.id and
            encargos.itemarticulosproveedor_id=items.id and 
            articulos.id=items.articulos_id       
        GROUP BY articulos.producto_id
    """,
    ()
))
```

The empty tuple in `RawSQL` is required since the function takes a `params` tuple argument that is not optional even when you have no parameters to pass.

As a bonus, `RawSQL` is less sensitive to prior `values`  calls and offers an optional `output_field` parameter when needed.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But still, i'm not getting a 'stock' field on my queryset. Do you know why?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is using `values()` before `extra()`, in which case the `extra` field is [silently discarded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: No, im using *values()* after the query to show/see if there's a stock field.

Comment: Then you'd need to debug the error that is lurking somewhere in your code. Or you can try the `RawSQL` alternative offered above, maybe it makes the problem go away.