# Why can't this subquery return more than one row?

Tags: mysql, django, database, subquery, django-orm

This **Query** is being generated by Django ORM using RawSQL:

```
SELECT `productos`.`codigo_barras`, (
        SELECT
            articulos.costo_us * (1 + articulos.iva_coef)
        FROM
            articulos
        INNER JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    articulos.id, MAX(encargosProveedor.fecha_entrega)
                FROM
                    articulos, encargosProveedor_listado_articulos, encargosProveedor, itemArticulosProveedor
                WHERE
                    articulos.id = itemArticulosProveedor.articulos_id AND
                    encargosProveedor.id = encargosProveedor_listado_articulos.encargosproveedor_id
                GROUP BY
                    articulos.producto_id
            )
        AS ultimos ON articulos.id = ultimos.id
) AS `ultimo_precio` FROM `productos`
```

It's giving an **error**

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

This is the result of the **subquery**

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | MAX(encargosProveedor.fecha_entrega) |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 |              2019-04-17              |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  3 |              2019-04-17              |
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

I read the MYSQL documentation but i can't understand why is there a problem with returning two rows. I've tried a lot of alternatives.

**Where is the problem?**

Comment: It's the same problem as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755605/why-does-django-queryset-extra-throws-operationalerror-1242-subquery-retur): You need to relate the rows in the outer query to the rows in the inner queries, e.g. via `WHERE articulos.producto_id = productos.id` or by making a join to the middle query: `... FROM productos INNER JOIN (SELECT ...) AS ultimo_precio ON ultimo_precio.producto_id = productos.id`. Obviously you also need to expose `producto_id` from the innermost to the middle query.

Comment: Thanks Endre. Yes, after reading the responses and more docs i've discoverd the concept of *correlated subqueries* and finally made the proper changes on this query.

Comment: For the ones with similar problems, an articule that i found very helpful was this:  https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/#fromHistory

Comment: @Hernan if you did find a solution to this problem you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries included as columns of a `SELECT` statement are called "scalar subqueries". A scalar subquery should be able to produce zero or one row only since its value (the scalar) will be placed in the returned row of the result set of the query, where there's room for one value only. Therefore, if a subquery returns more than a single row, it cannot be used directly as a `SELECT` column.

One option is to force it to produce one row at most, maybe using an aggregation function such as `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `COUNT()`, etc.

Another option is to join the subquery as a "table expression", where there are no restriction on the number of returned rows.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

It's not the

```
SELECT articulos.id, MAX(encargosProveedor.fecha_entrega) 
FROM ...
```

subquery that's the problem. As that is part of a `JOIN` expression it is allowed to return more than one row. *However*, since that returns more than one row, the surrounding subquery:

```
SELECT articulos.costo_us * (1 + articulos.iva_coef)
FROM articulos
INNER JOIN (SELECT articulos.id, MAX(encargosProveedor.fecha_entrega)
            FROM ...)
```

will also return more than one row.

You need to figure out a way to prevent the outer subquery returning more than one row even when the inner one does, possibly by using aggregation functions such as `MIN` or `MAX`. Alternatively, you need to find a way to distinguish between rows in the inner subquery that have the same `MAX(encargosProveedor.fecha_entrega)` value (perhaps ordering by another value with a `LIMIT 1`) so that query only returns one row.